# Need help translating this sentence

Tags: перевод

Всем привет! Мне нужно помощь с переводом этого предложения.

"Anna Borisovna gave Viktor Stepanovich money to buy groceries"

I tried translating it, but I got two different things and I want to know which one is "more" correct.

Анна Борисовна дала денег, чтобы Виктор Степанович купил продукты
или
Анна Борисована дала денег Виктору Степановичу, чтобы он купил продукты

Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct. But the first one is a bit confusing because it is unknown to whom she gave the money. As a native speaker i like the second sentence more.
Удачи в изучении русского языка =)

Answer (score 4):

> Анна Борисовна дала денег Виктору Степановичу, чтобы он купил
>   продукты

This is correct translation, **the reason is that** the 1st rendering

> Анна Борисовна дала денег, чтобы Виктор Степанович купил продукты

could be understood in a sense that Анна Борисовна gave money, but not necessarily to Виктор Степанович, it could be a 3d person who'd pass it on to Виктор Степанович or just pay for groceries selected by Виктор Степанович.

Basically it's as ambiguous as the English

> Anna Borisovna gave money so that Viktor Stepanovich would buy groceries

Answer (score 2):

Both variants are right. A slight correction can be "чтобы тот купил продукты", but it's optional.

And in the colloquial speech we would say

> Анна Борисовна дала Виктору Степановичу денег на продукты.